# Is my method right for gargabe collecting circular referenced objects?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, weak-references, circular-reference

When I was playing with my newly created html module, I used weakref module to overcome the circular reference problem. Everything seems to be fine for me! but I am not sure about the way I followed and not sure about the `Scope` class below. I tried to have a smallest working example (Here is a [link](https://bitbucket.org/ozanhaci/py2ml/src/3b2ab576260448781b551fa04cd4fdb5449634a1/py2ml/html.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) for full code). `Html` class is just for creating html output with python objects. The example below does not do that for simplicity, of course.

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import weakref


class Scope(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref_holder = set()

    def add(self, obj):
        self.ref_holder.add(obj)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ref_holder = None


class Html(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, tag="", scope=None):
        self.scope = scope
        if parent is None:
            self.parent = None
        elif type(parent) != weakref.CallableProxyType:
            self.parent = weakref.proxy(parent)
            if self.scope:
                self.scope.add(parent)
            elif parent.scope:
                parent.scope.add(self)
        else:
            self.parent = parent
        self.tag = tag
        if self.scope:
            self.scope.add(self)
        self.children = []

    def append(self, html):
        if isinstance(html, basestring):
            html = Html(tag=html)
            return self.append(html)
        elif isinstance(html, self.__class__):
            self.children.append(html)
            return html
        else:
            raise Exception("Unknown type")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Html "{tag}" children = {children}'.format(tag=self.tag,
                                            children=list(map(str, self.children)))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__unicode__()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Scope() as scope:
        test_form = Html(tag="form", scope=scope)
        test_form.append(Html(tag="label"))
        test_input = Html(tag="input")
        test_form.append(test_input)
        print(test_form)
```

Here are my concerns and I will appreciate your guidance:

I call reference holder class as `Scope`. It just holds the references to objects even if they are not assigned to any variable so `Html` object is not garbage collected (note: some objects can change parent/child relation ship and therefore there is not left any strong reference to object, in the real code).

I could simply hold the object references in a list and delete it after that but using `with` statement seems nicer. Is the class name `Scope` right for this task and the way I hold references is right? Is there a good way to hold the objects' strong references created on the fly different than my method?

I believe setting the `Scope.ref_holder` variable to `None` after exiting with statement, frees all the strong references and then `gc` collects them. I tested this by disabling `gc` and calling `gc.collect` then no object exists as unreacable, am I right to assume this method assures there is no leakage?

---

### EDIT

1. I added the [link](https://bitbucket.org/ozanhaci/py2ml/src/3b2ab576260448781b551fa04cd4fdb5449634a1/py2ml/html.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) for full source code.
2. Code is compliant with **Python 2.7**

Comment: Looking at linked code, why do you do `self.scope.add(self)` ? That's a circular reference in itself. P.S. circular references between pure-Python objects are not that bad, they are eventually collected, what you have to watch out for are: seesaw memory usage (quality concern), long-lived objects (accumulate a lot of crud), native objects in extension libraries (often poorly written)

Comment: I added `self.scope.add(self)` to guarantee not to collect the objects created on the fly without strong reference (no variable assignment). Since scope clears out all refs, there becomes garbage-less.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point here is that you are using `__exit__` matched with `with` in Python.

Basically it should not happen like this. In `__enter__` you are returning the self, the `__exit__` should remove all the references. Are you sure that you don't have any exception in the middle? Due to exception `__exit__` may return false and your garbage collection may not be complete.

However to answer your question, I can tell you that the way you are making it `None` in the `__exit__` method is forceful garbage cleaning & I think it completely depends on the OS. If `self.ref_holder` is somehow liked with addressed of those objects, they may be cleaned properly.

Try to do `del self.ref_holder` rather. Assure more powerful cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit OT: why explicit class for scope?

How about something simpler instead?

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def scope():
    rv = set()
    try:
        yield rv
    finally:
        pass
        # if you must be explicit or 
        # if you want side-effect in leaked scopes
        rv.clear()
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option for scope. Thank you.